Power BI report builder - creating a date parameter
I am building a paginated report on Power BI Report Builder. The data source is from Dataverse (data collected from a Power App). My dataset has a field called "ProductionTimeDate" and is in Date/Time. I am trying to create a parameter that will allow the user to filter their results to only a single day or group of days based on the "ProductionTimeDate" column.
I would expect this to be a fairly easy task but when I attempted to create a parameter using Query Designer, no results were returned.
Current Query:
SELECT
  [crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_unitnumber
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_materialname
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_teststatusname
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_comments
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_unitweightlbs
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_densitygl
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_clumpweightg
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_looselabelppm
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_attachedlabelcountnumber
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_pvcppm
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_aluminumppm
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_petgcountnumber
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_colorppm
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_barrierppm
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_gluecountnumber
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_washcolor
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_moisturepercent
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_productiondatetime
  ,[crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_shiftname
FROM
  crec4_lab_results AS [crec4_lab_results 0]
WHERE
  [crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_shiftname = @ajn_shiftname
  AND [crec4_lab_results 0].ajn_productiondatetime = @ajn_productiondatetime

Any suggestions on how I can make this parameter behave the way I want?



